# Strange behaviour for chainned transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, transactions, annotations, spring-aop

I don't get how it works the transactional annotations of Spring. So I made the next test with no practical sense but I It shows my problem:

```
public class TransactionalTest {
    public void noTransaction(){
        required();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public void supports(){
        required();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void transaction(){
        required();
    }

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void required(){
        mandatory();
    }

    @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_UNCOMMITTED, propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
    public void mandatory(){
        doSomething();
    }

    private void doSomething(){
        //I don't feel like to do something.
    }
}
```

Methods `noTransaction`, `supports` and `transaction` call to the same method: `required` but only the last one (`transaction`) works properly. The two others give me back the message **No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'**.

In the real case, I have some non transactional methods which calls to transactional methods annotated with `REQUIRED` (It works fine). but if a non transactional method calls to a transactional method (annotated with `REQUIRED`) which it calls to another transactional method annoted with `MANDATORY`, it fails.

Why this behaviour and how can avoid it? I annotated annotate all the method which calls to a transaccional method just in case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the default AOP method, Spring Proxy AOP, the advice is implemented by wrapping the annotated class with a proxy object that intercepts and advises the calls. When you use self-calls like this, you're bypassing the proxy, and the advice doesn't get applied.

If you really do need to have advice applied on self-calls, you need to use AspectJ AOP, which actually modifies the class in question instead of decorating it.